# Calling a C++ program (with arguments) inside Objective-C and grabbing the output

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a console-based C++ executable that has been successfully compiled for iPhone (arm7, arm7s, and i386 architectures). I would like to simply call this program (with arguments) and print back the output of the execution. Any ideas on how to go about doing this? In C++ this is done via some kind of popen() thing, but I have no idea how to approach this via Objective-C (especially since there doesn't seem to be any documentation on it).

Comment: popen() is part of the C library, so it should also work in Objective-C. That said, if you're running on iOS, I don't think one custom application can launch another directly, though I could be wrong...

Comment: @DariusMakaitis What do you mean by "directly"? How could one go by indirectly?

Comment: If you create an app that responds to a custom URL scheme, you can launch that app by opening a URL with the custom scheme: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, you could use [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this. On iOS your application can't run other processes. You'll have to compile and link the C++ code into your iOS app, and call its functions directly (essentially replacing its `main()`). Do you mind saying what the C++ executable is?